# how to override payment methods.phtml file in custom module in magento

Tags: php, magento, overriding

I have added a custom payment module and i want to that module can override the methods.phtml that is currently present in app/design/frontend/base/default/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml. how i can overirde that file ?

Answer (score 1):

One of the wisest thing to do is to create your own path

i.e  app/design/frontend/[theme_name]/template/checkout/payment/methods.phtml

don't forget to override the existing block as well by following

http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/

as its safe if you write your own codes rather than editing core files.